# client get not connected in pfsense openvpn site to site

Tags: openvpn, pfsense, site-to-site-vpn

I am trying to connect pfsense openvpn site to site (peer to peer shared key), but upto now I could not found any traffic between client and server.

**openvpn server log**

```
Listening for incoming TCP connection on [AF_INET]192.168.1.5:1194
```

**openvpn client log**

```
TCP: connect to [AF_INET]192.168.1.5:1194 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: Host is down
```

apart from firwall rule(WAN + OpenVpn) anything we need to configure in client side.

I followed the same firewall rule for both server and client

**firewall -> rule -> WAN**

[image]

**firewall -> rule -> OpenVpn**

[image]

**Note:** If you need more info please mention in comment.

when I see the status of the openvpn it is look like below (**it is running**)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing maybe you still have block private networks enabled on WAN? If you're connecting in from 192.168.1.x at least, and WAN is really a LAN in your case.

On an unrelated note, it's always preferable to use UDP for VPNs unless TCP is required for some reason (can't pass UDP between client and server).

Comment: uncheck the option "Block private networks and loopback addresses" in wan interface, but still the client connection failed

Comment: when I use UDP I got error "UDP RemoteLink[undef]", that is why I switch over to TCP

Comment: That's just what you see when UDP has no connectivity, same issue, just shows differently. Has nothing to do with TCP vs. UDP.