# set WAN IP in pfsense openvpn site to site connection?

Tags: openvpn, pfsense, site-to-site-vpn

I am new to networking, I am trying to connect two networks using **pfsense openvpn site to site** connection but upto now I can't successful. Please see my configuration [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/790920/client-get-not-connected-in-pfsense-openvpn-site-to-site/791006#791006).

**basics idea is**

[image]

most of the one suggest your WAN is look like private that is why it does not access from internet, actually in WAN interface I set DHCP after that it will automatically assign WAN 192.168.1.5. Here really I don't know how to make it public wan?

**I tried like this**

1) found my wanip using ipchicken.com

2) in WAN interface set static ip, assign ip what I found from ipchicken.com then set default gateway 192.168.1.1 after that I lost my internet connection.

can anyone assist me how to set wan ip for site to site connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just assign your WAN IP. The modem or whatever upstream device you have has to either be in bridge mode, so the firewall behind it gets your public IP, or otherwise configured to pass through the public IP. Without knowing what you're plugged into upstream, can't offer any specific suggestions. Look into how to pass through your public IP with your modem.